# How to manage sound serialization in Gluon Charm Down Audio plugin

Tags: android, ios, audio, javafx, gluon

I'm having some trouble with the sounds serialization in the Gluon Charm Down Audio plugin at this link:

https://github.com/anktjsh/Gluon-Charm-Down-Plugin-Audio

Now i'll explain what i'm trying to figure out:

**EXAMPLE SCENARIO**

Imagine this scenario: i've got an audio for each achievement and a series of achivements one after the other at the end of a game. So, i need to have this result:

first sound play until the end -> at the end of the first audio the second audio starts -> this repeated for all the n achievements (and obviously sounds)

Can anyone could help me to understand how to do it in all the platforms (IOS, android and desktop)?

This is my try of codify it for desktop only (sorry for any possible mistake):

```
package com.gluonhq.charm.down.plugins.desktop;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Vector;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import com.gluonhq.charm.down.plugins.AudioService;

import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;

public class DesktopAudioService extends AudioService {

private MediaPlayer last;
private MediaPlayer lastInLoop;

private boolean isPlaying;

private Collection<MediaPlayer> mediaQueue = new Vector<MediaPlayer>();
private int queueIndex = 0;

@Override
public void play_inner(final String play) {

    if (last != null && isPlaying) {

        mediaQueue.add(new MediaPlayer(new Media(play)));
        queueIndex++;

        last.setOnEndOfMedia(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                playQueue();
            }
        });
    }

    try {

        if (!isPlaying) {
            last = new MediaPlayer(new Media(play));
            isPlaying = true;

            last.setOnReady(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {

                    last.play();
                    isPlaying = true;
                }
            });

            last.setOnEndOfMedia(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    isPlaying = false;
                }
            });
        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DesktopAudioService.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}

private void playQueue() {

    if (mediaQueue == null || mediaQueue.isEmpty())
        return;

    MediaPlayer p = (MediaPlayer) mediaQueue.toArray()[queueIndex - 1];

    p.setOnEndOfMedia(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            isPlaying = false;
            mediaQueue.remove(p);
            queueIndex--;
            playQueue();
        }

    });

    p.setOnReady(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            p.play();
            isPlaying = true;
        }
    });

}

public void playInLoop(final String play) {
    try {
        lastInLoop = new MediaPlayer(new Media(play));
        lastInLoop.setCycleCount(lastInLoop.INDEFINITE);
        lastInLoop.setVolume(0.4);
        lastInLoop.play();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DesktopAudioService.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}

public URL getResource(String s) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    StackTraceElement[] stackTraceElements = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
    return Class.forName(stackTraceElements[2].getClassName().replace(".lambda$null$1", "")).getResource(s);
}

@Override
public void stop() {
    if (last != null) {
        last.stop();
    }

    if (lastInLoop != null) {
        lastInLoop.stop();
    }
}

@Override
public void pause() {
}

@Override
public void resume() {
}

public boolean isOnPlay() {

    if (last != null)
        return last.getStatus().equals(MediaPlayer.Status.PLAYING);
    else
        return false;
}

}
```

Comment: Obviously that project you refer is not from Gluon, but an implementation of an audio plugin based on Gluon Charm Down. Anyway, does your Desktop version work? Then you should be able to modify the code of the Android/iOS implementations in the same way. I probably will get your use case out of the plugin itself, and only add to it what is needed, like a listener to know when a song has ended.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work. I cannot figure out what the problem is. Can you help me? With some prints i have seen that the actions that i set on p MediaPlayer variable are not executed. If we solve this problem, i'll be glad to give you that code (also android and IOS) so you can possibly integrate it in the plugin. To you or to anybody else manages this plugin.